# list of lists coordinates to a list of coordinates with space for SVG file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list

```
my_list = [[200.0, 10.0], [250.0, 190.0], [160.0, 210.0]]
```

I want get the list of these coordinate with space between them

```
req_list = "200,10 250,190 160,210"
```

to write these in SVG format for polygons.

I tried replacing "[]" with " " but replace doesn't work for an array

```
my_list.replace("[", " ")
```

Comment: "I tried replacing "[]" with " " but replace doesn't work for an array" Yes, this approach is nonsense because the list (we don't call them arrays) **does not contain** the `[` symbols etc. It is essential to understand what data types are, and how they work, in order to write sensible code. The approach is simple, and this is a common problem combining elementary techniques shown in the linked duplicates. Each sub-list needs to be joined up as a string, and then those strings need to be joined using the same technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the list and append them into an empty string defined, for example:

```py
req_list = ""
for cor in my_list:
    req_list += '{},{} '.format(int(cor[0]),int(cor[1]))
print(req_list[:-1])
```

Prints:

```
200,10 250,190 160,210
```

Indexed till -1 is to ignore the last white space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join` to the sublists:

```py
my_list = [[200.0, 10.0], [250.0, 190.0], [160.0, 210.0]]

req_list = " ".join(",".join(f"{int(v)}" for v in l) for l in my_list)
print(req_list)
```

Prints:

```
200,10 250,190 160,210
```